# regex for disallow all special characters but allow other language like Hebrew javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for checking if there is a special character in the string but I want to allow all other languages like Hebrew. Please help me if you can.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to need a lot more details than that. What defines a special character vs a foreign language character? How about some examples?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg why downvote ? I need to check if there is a special character in string. only special characters not any other language characters. Please help if you can.

Comment: Use XRegExp for Unicode property, or inspect and copy the relevant code from the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my solution. I am checking if any special characters are present in string with this regex.

```
/[-!$%^&*()_+@\s|~=`\\#{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/
```

I am not sure I am correct, please correct me if I am wrong or missing something.

Comment: Depends on how you define special characters, but I just tested this on my iPhone and found some more special characters displayed by default on the iPhone keyboard, thought you may find it useful : \U2022, \U00a5, \U00a3, \U20ac